# How can I resolve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in the case when increasing the heap size will mean delayed OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I'm trying to build an application where a client sends its screen to the server, the client only sends its screen if there is a difference between last send screen and the latest captured screen(so that the program is easy on the network). And the server uses a JFrame and JLabel to display the image. But the thing is after a minute or two the server is giving a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Please consider my code

```
public  void go() throws Exception
{
  s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000);
  remoteIP = s.getInetAddress(); 
  remoteIPOnly = remoteIP.toString().split("\\/");
  frame=new JFrame(remoteIPOnly[1]);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  InputStream iss=s.getInputStream();
  ObjectInputStream is=new ObjectInputStream(iss);
  JLabel a=new JLabel();
  while(!s.isClosed())
    {
      if((ImageIcon)is.readObject()!=null)
         {
           System.out.println("I got here");
           imageIcon=(ImageIcon) is.readObject();
           image=imageIcon.getImage();
           rendered = null;  
           if (image instanceof RenderedImage)  
              {  
                 rendered = (RenderedImage)image;  
              }   
           else  
              {  
               buffered = new BufferedImage(  
               imageIcon.getIconWidth(),  
               imageIcon.getIconHeight(),  
               BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB  
               );  
               g = buffered.createGraphics();  
               g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);  
               g.dispose();  
               rendered = buffered;  
              }
           frame.setSize(rendered.getWidth(),rendered.getHeight());
           a.setIcon(imageIcon);
           frame.add(a);
           frame.setVisible(true);

         }
       }
}
```

And here is my other piece of code, it is also showing the same problem, pls help me optimize it.

```
 while(true)
 {
   s=serversocket.accept();
   os=s.getOutputStream();
   oss=new ObjectOutputStream(os);
image1=r.createScreenCapture(newRectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
  imageicon=new ImageIcon(image1);
  oss.writeObject(imageicon);
  while(!s.isClosed()){
  image2=r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit
  ().getScreenSize()));
  b=checkIfImagesAreEqual(image1,image2);
  System.out.println(b);
  if(b==false){
  image1=image2;
  imageicon1=new ImageIcon(image2);
  oss.writeObject(imageicon1);
  oss.flush();
 }
```

Can anyone tell me if my logic for my purpose is correct or not and why am I getting the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap space and will extending the heap size help me as I'm planning for more than one client to be able to connect to the server?

Sorry if my question is dumb and any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you write the dumps in files and mmap() them for comparison?

Comment: Sorry sir i didn't get you?

Comment: Probably the BufferedImage can be reused, too much garbage in a short amount of time can cause OOM. BTW: You are reading every second image (once, the discarded in the if condition, later in the assignment.)

Comment: Have you tried expanding the heap size to see what happens?

Comment: There are two basic possibilities:  1) The app uses some peak amount of heap, and if you make the heap large enough to pass the peaks all will be copacetic.  2) The app is "leaking" heap, eg, due to repeatedly adding entries to a (perhaps unintentionally) linked list of objects.  In this case you will definitely have to find and fix the "leak".  Tools are available to help.

Comment: I haven't tried increasing the heap size as i feel the error will only be delayed. Since as of now the error afters after 2 min, increasing heap size will only delay the error to little while more. Pls correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I said you should try and write images to files, map them (with FileChannel.open(...).map(...)); then a simple .equals() between the two obtained `MappedByteBuffer`s will tell you whether the images are equal

Comment: By the way, it IS OK to call System.gc(). Yes it automatically gets called by the JVM as it sees fit, but if you know you're hogging up a bunch of memory (e.g. with a big o' BufferedImage) and then can free it, do so, and then call System.gc(). As you have apparently demonstrated, it is entirely possible to use too much memory too fast and explode your application. Not saying we're reverting to the days of malloc or anything, but a little myImage=null; System.gc(); never hurt anybody.

Comment: I doubt that would help. JVM runs garbage collection aggressively when the heap is about to be exhausted.

Comment: @captainroxors I understood your point but can you tell me where I should do that using the variables in the program

Comment: @fge oh no I don't need to compare the images only the changed images are accepted if the image are equal the client won't send it the server(the given code) at first place.

Comment: @MaciejTrybiło I promise it does help. I actually just ran into this problem recently handling some silly large images. One image wasnt enough to make the JVM panic into "[aggressive] garbage collection" but loading the second caused an OOM. But once I changed it to manually collect the first once I finished dealing with it, life was good.

Comment: @captainroxors sir can you explain in detail where I should makethe changes?

Answer (score 4):

You keep adding the label to the frame. Shouldn't you just add it once?

There is an another problem: `if((ImageIcon)is.readObject()!=null)` will read out an image and lose it. You should instead keep it and not read it inside the `if` block. For instance:

`if((imageIcon = (ImageIcon)is.readObject()) != null)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually signal for garbage collection after manually disposing of large objects. Also, general optimizing will help.

I would recommend (in your client):

1. Create the frame
2. Create a BufferedImage of sufficient size to draw incoming images.
3. Add said BufferedImage to an ImageIcon
4. Add said ImageIcon to your JLabel
5. Add said JLabel to said frame
6. Size your frame
7. Display the frame

Then in your loop

1. Read in an Image (only the Image, not an ImageIcon)
2. Get the above BufferedImage's graphics context
3. Draw the received image to said context.
4. Erase pointer to image
5. call System.gc();

See how that goes. Oh and if your inbound images are of varying size, you'll probably want to wipe the BufferedImage before drawing on it again else you get funky borders :-)

As for your server, it looks alright, I'd just ditch the ImageIcons and go with just passing plain old Images. Something like this:

Begin loop

1. accept socket (as youre doing)
2. get object output stream (as youre doing)
3. get image1 (as youre doing)
4. write image1

Begin inner loop

1. get image2 (as youre doing)
2. compare images (as youre doing)
3. if(!b)    (b==false works; it's just a somewhat odd way to write it)
4. image1 = image2
5. System.gc() (because that previous assignment removed the pointer to the old image1)
6. write image1
7. flush stream (as youre doing)

And if a perfectly clear image isnt manditory, you might also consider compressing the image
before sending it, and just dealing with it as a byte array; you'd wire much less information.

```
public static byte[] bufferedImageToJPEGBytes(BufferedImage bi){
    try{
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e){
        return null;
    }
}

public static BufferedImage jpegBytesToBufferedImage(byte[] bytes){
    try{
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(rightImageBytes);
        return ImageIO.read(bais);
    } catch (IOException e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then just use

```
oos.writeObject(bufferedImageToJPEGBytes(image1)); //server side
```

and

```
image = jpegBytesToBufferedImage((byte[]) ois.readObject()); //client side
```

Comment: sir thank you for the help, the above code is not failing this time but my other program is now showing the same problem. Do i post its code too?

Comment: It's your question. You do what you like. If it's the same problem, then yeah; it makes sense to.

Comment: I have given details on my second program as well, please kindly see if you could help me. Thank you once again.

Comment: Sir I resolved it, doing oss.reset() after oss.flush() resolves the error. Thanks for your help you helped me resolve the client side error.